# Can't update Mysql record

Tags: mysql

Since my last question was closed with my issue being half resolved I'm going to ask again, 
when I would submit my form to update a MySQL record I was getting a syntax error unless all the fields were filled out. I was given a solution to fix it which does allow the form to update the record without all the fields being filled out but instead of passing the data posted in the fields all the form posts is a number 1 in all of the fields of the database.  What's the solution to this?

```
    <?php
//  Database ID //
$id=$_POST['id'];
//  section 1 column 1 row 1 - 5 //
$item_qty1=(isset($_POST['item_qty1'])
$item_qty2=(isset($_POST['item_qty2']) 
$item_qty3=(isset($_POST['item_qty3'])
$item_qty4=(isset($_POST['item_qty4']) 
$item_qty5=(isset($_POST['item_qty5']) 
// section 1 column 2 row 1 - 5 //
$manuf_1=(isset($_POST['manuf_1']) AND !empty($_POST['manuf_1'])? $_POST['manuf_1'] : '');
$manuf_2=(isset($_POST['manuf_2']) AND !empty($_POST['manuf_2'])? $_POST['manuf_2'] : '');
$manuf_3=(isset($_POST['manuf_3']) AND !empty($_POST['manuf_3'])? $_POST['manuf_3'] : '');
$manuf_4=(isset($_POST['manuf_4']) AND !empty($_POST['manuf_4'])? $_POST['manuf_4'] : '');
$manuf_5=(isset($_POST['manuf_5']) AND !empty($_POST['manuf_5'])? $_POST['manuf_5'] : '');

// section 1 column 3 row 1 - 5 //
$part_number1=(isset($_POST['part_number1']) AND !empty($_POST['part_number1'])? $_POST['part_number1'] : '');
$part_number2=(isset($_POST['part_number2']) AND !empty($_POST['part_number2'])? $_POST['part_number2'] : '');
$part_number3=(isset($_POST['part_number3']) AND !empty($_POST['part_number3'])? $_POST['part_number3'] : '');
$part_number4=(isset($_POST['part_number4']) AND !empty($_POST['part_number4'])? $_POST['part_number4'] : '');
$part_number5=(isset($_POST['part_number5']) AND !empty($_POST['part_number5'])? $_POST['part_number5'] : '');
// section 1 column 4 row 1 - 5 //
$part_description1=(isset($_POST['part_description1']) AND !empty($_POST['part_description1'])? $_POST['part_description1'] : '');
$part_description2=(isset($_POST['part_description2']) AND !empty($_POST['part_description2'])? $_POST['part_description2'] : '');
$part_description3=(isset($_POST['part_description3']) AND !empty($_POST['part_description3'])? $_POST['part_description3'] : '');
$part_description4=(isset($_POST['part_description4']) AND !empty($_POST['part_description4'])? $_POST['part_description4'] : '');
$part_description5=(isset($_POST['part_description5']) AND !empty($_POST['part_description5'])? $_POST['part_description5'] : '');
// section 1 column 5 row 1 - 5 //
$part_price1=(isset($_POST['part_price1']) AND !empty($_POST['part_price1'])? $_POST['part_price1'] : '');
$part_price2=(isset($_POST['part_price2']) AND !empty($_POST['part_price2'])? $_POST['part_price2'] : '');
$part_price3=(isset($_POST['part_price3']) AND !empty($_POST['part_price3'])? $_POST['part_price3'] : '');
$part_price4=(isset($_POST['part_price4']) AND !empty($_POST['part_price4'])? $_POST['part_price4'] : '');
$part_price5=(isset($_POST['part_price5']) AND !empty($_POST['part_price5'])? $_POST['part_price5'] : '');
// section 1 column 6 row 1 - 5 //
$price_extension1=(isset($_POST['price_extension1']) AND !empty($_POST['price_extension1'])? $_POST['price_extension1'] : '');
$price_extension2=(isset($_POST['price_extension2']) AND !empty($_POST['price_extension2'])? $_POST['price_extension2'] : '');
$price_extension3=(isset($_POST['price_extension3']) AND !empty($_POST['price_extension3'])? $_POST['price_extension3'] : '');
$price_extension4=(isset($_POST['price_extension4']) AND !empty($_POST['price_extension4'])? $_POST['price_extension4'] : '');
$price_extension5=(isset($_POST['price_extension5']) AND !empty($_POST['price_extension5'])? $_POST['price_extension5'] : '');
// end of section 1 totals //
$material_cost=$_POST['material_cost'];
$sales_tax=$_POST['sales_tax'];
$shipping_cost=$_POST['shipping_cost'];
// section 2 row 1 //
$work_performed=$_POST['work_performed'];
// section 3 cloumn 1 row 1  - 5 //
$work_date1=(isset($_POST['work_date1']) AND !empty($_POST['work_date1'])? $_POST['work_date1'] : '');
$work_date2=(isset($_POST['work_date2']) AND !empty($_POST['work_date2'])? $_POST['work_date2'] : '');
$work_date3=(isset($_POST['work_date3']) AND !empty($_POST['work_date3'])? $_POST['work_date3'] : '');
$work_date4=(isset($_POST['work_date4']) AND !empty($_POST['work_date4'])? $_POST['work_date4'] : '');
$work_date5=(isset($_POST['work_date5']) AND !empty($_POST['work_date5'])? $_POST['work_date5'] : '');
// section 3 column 2 row 1 - 5 //
$tech_name1=(isset($_POST['tech_name1']) AND !empty($_POST['tech_name1'])? $_POST['tech_name1'] : '');
$tech_name2=(isset($_POST['tech_name2']) AND !empty($_POST['tech_name2'])? $_POST['tech_name2'] : '');
$tech_name3=(isset($_POST['tech_name3']) AND !empty($_POST['tech_name3'])? $_POST['tech_name3'] : '');
$tech_name4=(isset($_POST['tech_name4']) AND !empty($_POST['tech_name4'])? $_POST['tech_name4'] : '');
$tech_name5=(isset($_POST['tech_name5']) AND !empty($_POST['tech_name5'])? $_POST['tech_name5'] : '');
// section 3 column 3 row 1 - 5 //
$cost_code1=(isset($_POST['cost_code1']) AND !empty($_POST['cost_code1'])? $_POST['cost_code1'] : '');
$cost_code2=(isset($_POST['cost_code2']) AND !empty($_POST['cost_code2'])? $_POST['cost_code2'] : '');
$cost_code3=(isset($_POST['cost_code3']) AND !empty($_POST['cost_code3'])? $_POST['cost_code3'] : '');
$cost_code4=(isset($_POST['cost_code4']) AND !empty($_POST['cost_code4'])? $_POST['cost_code4'] : '');
$cost_code5=(isset($_POST['cost_code5']) AND !empty($_POST['cost_code5'])? $_POST['cost_code5'] : '');
// section 3 column 4 row 1 - 5 //
$pay_rate1=(isset($_POST['pay_rate1']) AND !empty($_POST['pay_rate1'])? $_POST['pay_rate1'] : '');
$pay_rate2=(isset($_POST['pay_rate2']) AND !empty($_POST['pay_rate2'])? $_POST['pay_rate2'] : '');
$pay_rate3=(isset($_POST['pay_rate3']) AND !empty($_POST['pay_rate3'])? $_POST['pay_rate3'] : '');
$pay_rate4=(isset($_POST['pay_rate4']) AND !empty($_POST['pay_rate4'])? $_POST['pay_rate4'] : '');
$pay_rate5=(isset($_POST['pay_rate5']) AND !empty($_POST['pay_rate5'])? $_POST['pay_rate5'] : '');
// section 3 column 5 row 1 - 5 //
$total_hours1=(isset($_POST['total_hours1']) AND !empty($_POST['total_hours1'])? $_POST['total_hours1'] : '');
$total_hours2=(isset($_POST['total_hours2']) AND !empty($_POST['total_hours2'])? $_POST['total_hours2'] : '');
$total_hours3=(isset($_POST['total_hours3']) AND !empty($_POST['total_hours3'])? $_POST['total_hours3'] : '');
$total_hours4=(isset($_POST['total_hours4']) AND !empty($_POST['total_hours4'])? $_POST['total_hours4'] : '');
$total_hours5=(isset($_POST['total_hours5']) AND !empty($_POST['total_hours5'])? $_POST['total_hours5'] : '');
// section 3 column 6 row 5
$hours_subtotal1=(isset($_POST['hours_subtotal1']) AND !empty($_POST['hours_subtotal1'])? $_POST['hours_subtotal1'] : '');
$hours_subtotal2=(isset($_POST['hours_subtotal2']) AND !empty($_POST['hours_subtotal2'])? $_POST['hours_subtotal2'] : '');
$hours_subtotal3=(isset($_POST['hours_subtotal3']) AND !empty($_POST['hours_subtotal3'])? $_POST['hours_subtotal3'] : '');
$hours_subtotal4=(isset($_POST['hours_subtotal4']) AND !empty($_POST['hours_subtotal4'])? $_POST['hours_subtotal4'] : '');
$hours_subtotal5=(isset($_POST['hours_subtotal5']) AND !empty($_POST['hours_subtotal5'])? $_POST['hours_subtotal5'] : '');
// End of form totals //
$total_hours=$_POST['total_hours'];
$material_total=$_POST['material_total'];
$labor_cost=$_POST['labor_cost'];
$grand_total=$_POST['grand_total'];
```

Comment: Just a tip: when you use `empty()` to test a variable, you don't need to do `isset()` first (since `empty()` returns true when the variable is not set).  That will help reduce some of the clutter in your code

Comment: @itsmejodie well I was told to use isset because the form wouldn't process with empty fields. If I remove the isset I get a syntax error.

Comment: as an example: `$manuf_1 =  !empty($_POST['manuf_1']) ? $_POST['manuf_1'] : '';`

Comment: @itsmejodie ok I removed the isset from the equation and it submits but it doesn't submit the info in the fields, it just puts a number 1 in every field in the database.

Comment: I just tested your code and I confirm that I do not get '1' when I eliminate the `AND` (and the isset())

Comment: @itsmejodie ok I will remove the and and try again

Comment: @itsmejodie ok I got it working now, but now the rows in the first section duplicate their data down to the other 4 rows. so qty in the 1st row has 4 in it and it puts 4 in all the rows below it in the database even though they were empty when submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using `AND` instead of `&&`.

However, since the `isset()` is redundant you don't need && at all when we eliminate the call to `isset()`.  Example:

```
// section 1 column 5 row 1 - 5 //
$part_price1=!empty($_POST['part_price1'])? $_POST['part_price1'] : '';
$part_price2=!empty($_POST['part_price2'])? $_POST['part_price2'] : '';
$part_price3=!empty($_POST['part_price3'])? $_POST['part_price3'] : '';
$part_price4=!empty($_POST['part_price4'])? $_POST['part_price4'] : '';
$part_price5=!empty($_POST['part_price5'])? $_POST['part_price5'] : '';

// section 1 column 6 row 1 - 5 //
$price_extension1=!empty($_POST['price_extension1'])? $_POST['price_extension1'] : '';
$price_extension2=!empty($_POST['price_extension2'])? $_POST['price_extension2'] : '';
$price_extension3=!empty($_POST['price_extension3'])? $_POST['price_extension3'] : '';
$price_extension4=!empty($_POST['price_extension4'])? $_POST['price_extension4'] : '';
$price_extension5=!empty($_POST['price_extension5'])? $_POST['price_extension5'] : '';
```

As I mentioned in a comment, the call to `isset()` is not required when what you want to know is whether you have a non-empty value or not.

Comment: now I get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'empty' (T_EMPTY) in C:\xampp\htdocs\alpha\site1\data\var\variables.php on line 5

Comment: oh wait, I see you made some changes I didn't notice, let me try again

Comment: this is line 5 $item_qty1=!empty($_POST['item_qty1'])?  : '');

Comment: so I need to remove this entire section correct? (isset($_POST['item_qty5']) AND

Comment: itsmejodie ok I changed all the variables to match what you have above and now I get this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\alpha\site1\data\var\variables.php on line 19   and this is what line 19 is  $part_number2=!empty($_POST['part_number2'])? $_POST['part_number2'] : ";

Comment: wait I think I see it I have double quotes at the end instead of single quotes. Is that it?

Comment: itsmejodie thank you that solved my issue with getting all 1's and the form submission but now all five rows in the first section, so qty, manufacture, part number, description, price and ext duplicate their data down to the other 4 rows.

Comment: I figured it out, had nothing to do with the variables issue with the duplicating rows. Thanks itsmejodie for your assistance!